# Get Twitter Statuses and its replay by using LinqToTwitter + MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-twitter

By using TwitterContext.Search I'm able to retrieve statuses. But I need Status with replay of that particular status if Somebody has been replied. How to retrieve it? Anyone has experience in this please replay.

Comment: This one I have done with below query   var srch =
                                (from search in twitterCtx.Search
                   where search.Type == SearchType.Search           && search.Query == "to:" + "ScreenName" + " OR from:" + "ScreenName" &&  search.Count ==  100                             select search).SingleOrDefault();

But the problem is its retrieving only 46 feeds. And SearchMetaData , NextUrl is coming as NULL. So how to fix it ?

Comment: I have tried the same query in Twitter Search page there so many tweets are retrieving but through the above code I'm able to retrieve very less number of feed. Can any one help on this? Any pointers will be highly appreciated.